# Best approach when testing REST Endpoints

Tags: java, rest, testing

I'm looking at the following code which tests a REST Endpoint:

```
Response response = server.newRequest("/myresource").request().buildPost(Entity.text("42")).invoke();
assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
MyModel myModel = response.readEntity(MyModel.class);
assertEquals(42, myModel.getResult());
```

as outlined here:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-test-rest-api-junit

I'm wondering though is it best to convert the response to a MyModel object and apply the tests on this object. I would be more inclined to do this:

```
JSONObject expectedResponse = new JSONObject();
expectedResponse.put("name", "mkyong.com");
expectedResponse.put("age", new Integer(100));

assert(response, expectedResponse);
```

Which approach is best?

Comment: It really depends on how you use it in the code, if you are using the second method then stick with otherwise it doesn't make much of a sense. also try mocking those services for unit tests